# Rails 4 - OSX Lion , cannot access my routed pages from iPhone via Bonjour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bonjour, static-pages

(Rails 4 / Ruby 2.0 / gem  high_voltage (1.2.4) )

I am running fine my project in dev mode on my desktop having : 
    - my static xxxxx.html.erb page in /app/views/pages
    my routes defined :

```
  get 'home' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'home'
  get 'about' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'about'
  get 'page1' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'page1'
  get 'page2' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'page2'
```

running from my desktop   localhost:3000, it's fine I get my static pages ( home, about, ...)

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-16 14:55:38 +0200
Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
  Rendered pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (3.7ms)
http://0.0.0.0:3000  , I get to my about page
Started GET "/about" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-16 15:01:31 +0200
Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"about"}
  Rendered pages/about.html.haml within layouts/application (3.2ms)
```

but when running from my iPhone, via wifi in Safari browser   192.168.1.14:3000
I cannot get the same pages ...

```
    Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.11 at 2013-09-16 15:04:34 +0200
Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms
ActionController::RoutingError (No such page: home):

 192.168.1.14:3000/about
Started GET "/about" for 192.168.1.11 at 2013-09-16 15:03:39 +0200
Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"about"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms
ActionController::RoutingError (No such page: about):
```

where am I wrong with my  iPhone access via bonjour ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you access in a desktop browser with 192.168.1.14:3000 or only with localhost:3000?

Comment: both on desktop brother, got issue only in iPhone simulator